# Testing for a picture connected to a link

Tags: excel, vba

so I have been searching through this forum for quite a while now, and also on other sites, but I just could not find a way to solve this problem.

So the small problem I got is, that I have a very long Excel Spreadsheet, with many different ID's, or numbers whatever you want to call them. From these ID's I create a custom link, which needs them to direct to a specific image, that is then pasted into a specific cell in this spreadsheet. Note that I really need this code, hence the spreadsheet is about 9300 lines/rows long. The problem now is that not every id has an image attached to it, which means that some links do not work (no image there, but also no text basically an empty page). Is there a way I can just let the code run through it, so that it ignores the error 1004 which is generated, which basically is always telling me he could not find something and will stop at that point.

I am a big noob at VBA, so please when answering do not use to complicated language. I will paste the code below, however the link is confidential, so I will replace the link with "link" or something like that. I  tried several On Error methods, but either the error came up again, or Excel crashed, but here is the working code without any modifications to remove this error. Thanks in advance for all the help.

```
    Sub Test()

    I = 0

    For I = 5 To 9373

        If Tabelle2.Cells(I, 9) = "bekannt" Then
            Call GetShapeFromWeb("Part 1 of the link" & Tabelle2.Cells(I, 10).Value & "Part 2 of the link", Tabelle2.Cells(I, 13))
        End If

    Next I

End Sub

Sub GetShapeFromWeb(strShpUrl As String, rngTarget As Range)
    Dim shp As Shape

    With rngTarget
        With .Parent
                .Pictures.Insert strShpUrl 'Error Occurs here
                Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.count)
            End With
                shp.Left = .Left
                shp.Top = .Top
        End With

    Set shp = Nothing

End Sub
```

One last thing to notice, some of the words are german, due to me being german and working with german variables, or links, or spreadsheets. And I am using excel 2007. The Error occurs in the following row ".Pictures.Insert strShpUrl" because it can not find a picture to insert.

Thansk a lot.
Kind Regards
Chris

//EDIT
One Idea I might have, which I dont know if it is possible, but the page it is directed to, when a picture is not there it displays the following "Unable to find /part/of/thelink/"
Could one maybe use a code to see if this message is displayed, and maybe check for that? If so how would that work? :) Maybe it could be added to the if statement at the top which tests already for this sub task.

//EDIT
Anyone got some idea? :S Maybe what I posted above in the edit could work? :S Is it possible to check if a msgbox displays something but the other way around so if the msgbox does not equal the following do this. If that could work it would be great! :S Or maybe instead of trying the on error commands trying it with an if statement within the GetShapeFromWeb sub? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: point the line where your `1004 error` occurs.. do you take this pictures from the web (as suggest `strShpUrl variable` name) or from your local machine?

Comment: It is taken from an online link, so nothing locally, but I can not show the link its rather private or more confidential. But it is just a general link so the part 1 is like this /something/something/ then here stands the id frmo the excel sheet, and after that comes one more thing with an _ and a few letters. Thats it for the link.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. However you wrote that you tried several On Error Methods unsuccessfully ... what does this one for you?

```
Sub GetShapeFromWeb(strShpUrl As String, rngTarget As Range)
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Er As Long: Er = 0
    On Error GoTo gswError

    With rngTarget
        With .Parent
            .Pictures.Insert strShpUrl
            If Er <> 0 Then Exit Sub
            Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        End With
        shp.Left = .Left
        shp.Top = .Top
    End With

    Set shp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
gswError:
    Er = Err
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Like many other Error messages I have tried this one crashes the program for some reason. So its still loading in the background. But still thanks for the tipp, I just dunno why almost any "on error" code crashes the program. If you have any further I ideas I would appreciate if you could post them :).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried on the GetShapeFromWeb sub, placing the On Error statement this way:

```
Sub GetShapeFromWeb(strShpUrl As String, rngTarget As Range)
Dim shp As Shape

On Error GoTo Err1 'inserting a picture from a blank link will cause an error... thus...

With rngTarget
    With .Parent
            .Pictures.Insert strShpUrl
            Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        End With
            shp.Left = .Left
            shp.Top = .Top
    End With

Err1: '...sidestep

Set shp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Like the code below, sadly the program stops working. Gotta quit it now lucky I saved the previous one :D. Still thanks a lot for the tipp! :) I will also carry on to try and find a solution if I find somthing I will post it here.

Comment: did it freeze? maybe it was still busy running the code. If there're many links, it could take some time.

Comment: No it actually crashed, I usually let it run for quite some time, also did it with this sample (about 5 min) but nothing changes, and you know when clicking on it it becomes like greyed/whited out. I will run both posts again, just to make sure. (maybe it is that i will keep you updated)

Comment: Have you tried debugging step by step with F8 or inserting a break point for each sub call, and then running it (F5)? It could help identifying which values are causing the problem: make sure to inspect variables strShpUrl and rngTarget. Running it with break points you could identify what values are problematic. And save/make copies before running..

Comment: I am in debug mode all the time, but i will try this with f8 (your code is still running but program does not respond ;( ), and what do you mean with the break point? :) Thanks for the tipps so far, probably can close it now again the code does not seem to work :S

//EDIT so I went through it with F8 but it stopped exactly at the same positon it always stops. After some loops comes an id or a link which has no picture and this one crashes the code, because it can not find a picture. In other words Error 1004

Comment: A breakpoint is a marker placed on a line of code that causes execution to pause immediately before executing that line. You can add a breakpoint to a line of code by putting the cursor on the line of code in question and pressing F9, choosing Toggle Breakpoint on the Debug menu, or clicking in the left margin next to the line of code.

Comment: Okay none if that really worked :( also with the break point I did not notice anything that could be wrong with those variables. :S But already I gotta tell you thanks a lot for all the help and effort you put into helping me, really appreciate it. :)